# "Goal of math" or "Goal of mathematicians"?

Tags: grammaticality

This is a sentence from a post I made on the math.se site.

> The goal of professional, research mathematics is simple: proving the strongest possible theorems.

At first, instead of "mathematics", I had "mathematicians". For some reason that sounded slightly off to me. Are both variants acceptable?

Comment: *Mathematician* is definitely not the same thing as *mathematics,* so changing the word changes the meaning of the sentence. What has the goal? Is it mathematicians who have the goal (and mathematics is neutral), or is it a goal of mathematics itself (which gives mathematicians no choice but to aim for it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The goal of mathematics is to prove the strongest possible theorems

and

> The goal of mathematicians is to prove the strongest possible theorems

are both grammatical.

The first refers to the art itself, and it is part of the art to prove theorems. The second refers to the people practising the art, and it is part of their job to prove theorems. These two sentences, although not identical in meaning, are very similar.